# Use Typescript and nodejs to create a app that is not web or api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, microservices, structure

Is appropriate to use nodejs and typescript to make a service that is not an API or web application? Currently, I'm making a service who periodically read emails attachments and send the attachments to another app, save info about the emails in db etc.. It's working good, but i can't find in the internet examples of structure of a non-web app with typescript

What you think? I know it is possible because I have already done... But is appropriate? Do you have some examples where I can check? Cant find in GitHub either, I don't know how to call an app like this

Comment: sure, why not. Typescript is just a programming language, what you write in it is your choice. NPM is full of examples of libraries that are intended for non-web applications, e.g., in robotics we use rosnodejs to write robotics software in node.js.

Comment: @ChristianFritz Do you have some links of repositories that can help me get a base of structure

Comment: There is no common structure I can think of. Since the applications can be so vastly different, I can't quite imagine what sort of commonality there could be.

Comment: This is a great case for [Deno](https://deno.land/).

Comment: It wouldn't be my first choice for stuff I needed other people to use. It doesn't compile easily to native binaries (Go, Rust, C) and it's not ubiquitous like Python, meaning your users (or servers or docker images) will have to have node installed. I mean, certainly not the worst choice, especially not for e.g. tools for a team already familiar with/using TS, but this whole thing is just a big opinion fest and therefor off-topic for stack overflow. If it's for a service for your own servers (even if not web) yeah, sure, go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a CLI tool?

Maybe these repos could give you some help with structure/practices:

1. https://github1s.com/sindresorhus/trash
2. https://github1s.com/sindresorhus/speed-test
3. https://github1s.com/MrRio/vtop
4. https://github1s.com/millermedeiros/esformatter
5. https://github1s.com/gustavofabro/get-torrents-cli

https://www.google.com/search?q=most+popular+node+js+cli+tools

https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=cli

Typescript is an excellent choice for one-off scripting and CLI tools IMO.

Comment: "Typescript is an excellent choice for one-off scripting and CLI tools IMO." it doesn't compile easily to native binaries and it's not ubiquitous like Python, meaning your users (or servers or docker images) will have to have node installed. I mean, not the *worst* choice, but this whole thing is just a big opinion fest, and somebody can duke it out someplace else.